# Layers not overlapping in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, coordinate-system, layers, geotiff-tiff

I downloaded a bunch of wpts from my gps. I converted them to .SHP format with a CRS WGS 84  in QGIS, and started a new project. I then exported some satelite imagery from the internet as a tiff and imported it as a raster in my project as WGS 84. I have CRS 'on the fly, enabled, but I still cannot see both layers at once. I can zoom between layers but they wont overlay.

Answer (score 0):

After working on this all day, I finally figured it out. 
I was importing the tiff with the wrong projection.